# Can I programmatically install new version of .NET using .NET?

Tags: c#

Let's say, I have a .NET 2 installed. Can I programmatically install version 4 using .NET 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course you can. Include the required installation package and then [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx), or even better: make a setup and deployment project for your application and set a launch condition to .NET 4.0 so that when someone tries to install it it will verify the presence of .NET 4.0 and if not ask to install it:

[image]

Remark: in the screenshot set .NET 4.0 as launch condition (step 4)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (just shell out to installer MSI and msiexec.exe), but there are things like lock downs and other security issues to consider. But it's better practise to tell the user to install it and then install your program. Your installer will need to be .net 2.0 code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Just start the installer process.

```
Process.Start("dotnetfx.exe");
```